# How do I compile Magento 2 LESS media queries with Gulp

Tags: gulp, less, media-queries, magento2

I've written a gulp script that basically compiles all of my custom styling on top of my magento 2 theme. And it compiles all of the css apart from the css that is in the LESS Media query mixin:

```
.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'max') and (@break = @screen__s) {
```

I've tried quite a lot from googling the problem to reading and understanding how the mixin works. I find it odd that I don't get an error in my terminal.

```
function compile(done) {
  const brandPaths = ["gcn", "gtn", "embn", "gmbn"];

  brandPaths.forEach(brand => {
    src(`app/design/frontend/Playsports/theme_frontend_${brand}/web/css/source/_base-theme.less`)
      .pipe(less())
      .pipe(minifyCSS())
      .pipe(rename({ suffix: ".min" }))
      .pipe(dest(`app/design/frontend/Playsports/theme_frontend_${brand}/Magento_Theme/web/`));
    done();
  });
}

function watchChange(done) {
  watch("app/design/frontend/Playsports/**/*.less", series(compile));
  done();
}
```

I would expect my gulp script to compile the media queries as well but this is the problem I'm having

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for something that stays with core magento style and structures, our team has developed this [bobmotor/magento-2-gulp](https://github.com/bobmotor/magento-2-gulp) that supports:

- default magento 2 project structure with theme config inside `dev/tools/grunt/configs/themes.js`
- installation with `composer`
- `.less`
- `browsersync` and `liverreload`
- compiling es6+ with `Babel`
- creating `svg` sprites
- compiling `critical.css` (Magento 2.3.3)